# Excel Data Validation as input to another Data Validation

Tags: excel, list, validation, dynamic

Assuming I have a worksheet with the following information:

```
Manager    Division
Gustavo        1
John           2
Jack           2
Paul           1
Simona         2
```

I have a data validation list that allows the user to select a division.
If the user selects 1, then in another data validation list I want to list Gustavo and Paul. IF the user selects 2, then in another data validation list I want to list John, Jack and Simona.
Moreover, the data might scale. What I mean is: maybe below Simona another user can be added, let's say: Berry 1. Then if the user selects 1, then Gustavo, Paul and Berry will be the options for the other data validation list.

I have already implemented the first validation list. The problem I am having is with the second part of the problem. Most solutions out there uses name managers. This is a problem for me because the way my data is laid out and because I need to keep constantly updating name managers. I would like to make it more dynamic, when a user adds or remove data, it always shows the current list for that division. I will have a third validation list afterwards, however, if I can learn how to do this one, then I should be able to solve the rest of the problem.

Comment: Does this selection only happen once in the sheet, or is it on every row that they select the division and then the manager?

Comment: The division is only selected once. It is always at cell $D$4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you can do this in a couple of steps with a working range to hold the validation list:

1. Somewhere in your workbook, you create an array formula in multiple cells

   - select cells e.g. F2:F6 (I'm using 5 possible Managers per division in the example, but you can change that)
   - With them all selected, enter the ARRAY formula (i.e. use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter it) `=SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$6=$D$4,ROW($B$2:$B$6),""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:5")))` - the managers' divisions are in B2:B6 - the selected one is in D4... the `1:5` is a effectively a counter, going up to our 5 possible managers.
   - This should give you a list of row numbers where the Division is the same as selected and then some `#NUM!` errors
2. In the next column (G2:G6) enter the (normal) formula `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("A"&F2),"")`. This will give you a list of the names of Managers in the selected division.
3. In the cell you want the selection, use the source `=OFFSET($G$2,0,0,COUNT($F$2:$F$6))` - this references the list of names, but gets rid of the blanks at the bottom

Hope this makes sense! Here is a picture of the layout:[image]

Comment: The OP mentioned dynamic data for the managers, so I bet your answer would be most helpful if you can make it dynamic as well. Using `OFFSET` perhaps.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to work out how to adjust that solution to my problem.

Comment: Hi @StorymasterQ, it is dynamic - if you change the selected Division in D4, the drop-down changes

Comment: The range B2:B6 can go over the end of the list e.g. B2:B999... So if you add a manager, it will automatically be included.

Comment: @GustavoBaiocchiCosta let me know if you need any help! And good luck!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6fnrtgjpyhgr0d/Example.xlsx Here is a link to example file. How can I make the Data Validation on Sheet1.Cell($G$4) based on the value on cell $D$4?

Comment: Here is the completed one: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yks80n61a3fx9ac/Example.xlsx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59728/discussion-between-captain-and-gustavo-baiocchi-costa).