# Excel VBA Dependent combo boxes

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

On this website http://www.thesmallman.com/blog/2016/9/15/dependent-and-non-dependent-comboboxes I found the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim rng As Range 'set the worksheet range for the procedure.
Dim r As Range 'range for the loop
Dim Dic As Object 'name for the dictionary
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set sh = Sheet2 'Control Sheet
Set ws = Sheet3 'List Sheet

Set rng = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    For Each r In rng
        Dic(r.Value) = Empty
    Next

    With ComboBox1
        .ListFillRange = ""
            If .ListCount = 0 Then 'Take out to refresh
                .List = Application.Transpose(Dic.keys)
                .ListIndex = 0
            End If ' out to refresh
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change() 'Funding Combo Box capital program yr
Dim rng As Range 'set the worksheet range for the procedure.
Dim r As Range 'range for the loop
Dim Dic As Object 'name for the dictionary
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim cb As ComboBox
Dim ar As Variant

Set sh = Sheet2 'Control Sheet
Set ws = Sheet3 'List Sheet

ar = Array("All Sub Categories", "All Products")
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set rng = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
Set sh = Sheet2 'Control Sheet

    For Each r In rng
        If r = ComboBox1 Then
            Dic(r.Offset(, 1).Value) = Empty
        End If
    Next

    With ComboBox2 'Add data to the comboboxes
        .List = Application.Transpose(Dic.keys)
        .AddItem "All Categories", 0
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
    'Add to cb 3 & 4
    For i = 3 To 4
      Dic.RemoveAll
        For Each r In rng
            If r = ComboBox1 Then
                Dic(r.Offset(, i - 1).Value) = Empty
            End If
        Next

        Set cb = Sheet1.Shapes("ComboBox" & i).OLEFormat.Object.Object
        With cb 'Add data to the comboboxes
            .List = Application.Transpose(Dic.keys)
            .AddItem ar(i - 2), 0
            .ListIndex = 0
        End With
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 4 'Loop through the comboboxes
        Set cb = Sheet1.Shapes("ComboBox" & i).OLEFormat.Object.Object
        sh.Cells(2, i + 1) = cb.Value
    Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change() 'Geography Program
Dim rng As Range 'set the worksheet range for the procedure.
Dim r As Range 'range for the loop
Dim Dic As Object 'name for the dictionary
Dim i As Integer
Dim cb As ComboBox
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set sh = Sheet2 'Control Sheet
Set ws = Sheet3 'List Sheet

Application.EnableEvents = False
Set rng = ws.Range("B2", ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    If ComboBox2 = "All Categories" Then
        For Each r In rng
            Dic(r.Offset(, 1).Value) = Empty
        Next

        Else
        'Only items that relate to Combo 2
        For Each r In rng
            If r = ComboBox2 Then
                Dic(r.Offset(, 1).Value) = Empty
            End If
        Next
    End If

    With ComboBox3 'Add data to the comboboxes
        .List = Application.Transpose(Dic.keys)
        .AddItem "All Sub Categories", 0
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With

    Dic.RemoveAll
    'NEW
        'Only items that relate to Combo 2
        For Each r In rng
            If r = ComboBox2 Then
                Dic(r.Offset(, 2).Value) = Empty
            End If
        Next


    With ComboBox4 'Add data to the comboboxes
        .List = Application.Transpose(Dic.keys)
        .AddItem "All Products", 0
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With

    sh.[c2] = ComboBox2.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
Dim rng As Range 'set the worksheet range for the procedure.
Dim r As Range 'range for the loop
Dim Dic As Object 'name for the dictionary
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set sh = Sheet2 'Control Sheet
Set ws = Sheet3 'List Sheet

Application.EnableEvents = False
Set rng = ws.Range("C2", ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    If ComboBox3 = "All Sub Categories" Then
        For Each r In rng
            Dic(r.Offset(, 1).Value) = Empty
        Next

        Else
        'Only items that relate to Combo 3
        For Each r In rng
            If r = ComboBox3 Then
                Dic(r.Offset(, 1).Value) = Empty
            End If
        Next
    End If

    With ComboBox4
        .List = Application.Transpose(Dic.keys)
        .AddItem "All Products", 0
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
    sh.[D2] = ComboBox3.Value
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox4_Change()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheet2 'Control Sheet

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    sh.[E2] = ComboBox4.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End
End Sub
```

I understand some of the code but not all of it as I am a beginner in VBA. I would like to learn how to modify this code to give me 2 comboboxes where the second combo box is dependent on the first one. I would also like to remove all the code that is not directly tied to the updating of the first and second combo boxes. This thread is interesting:[Excel Data Validation as input to another Data Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422262/excel-data-validation-as-input-to-another-data-validation)

**UPDATE:**

I uploaded an image with the source of the lists, green text is the nondependent drop down list and the red text is dependent drop downs. [Image of my data layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5uYd.png)

Comment: How many entries will there be in the first dropdown? Is the usual method of creating named ranges whose names are the same as each list item in the first combo not an option? See here for easy tutorial http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the first dropdown there will be 25 to 29 entries.  At the moment I am using named ranges in data validation lists, however I don't like that the "arrow" goes away when it is not selected. That is why I would like to use combo boxes instead with VBA.

Comment: You can use the same idea with combo boxes using the named range to populate the second drop down via the change event of the first drop down combo box

Comment: You pass the current selected item from box 1 to box 2 and as it is named range it can be used to provide the dependent values to the second.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion QHarr. I will try it. I am still interested in the VBA code above, I want to learn VBA !

Comment: You may wish to show how your data is laid out as well so it is clear where different list values are being source from.

Comment: I uploaded an image with my data layout. I am thankful for any help I can get.

Comment: Are those the dependent lists? Where is the main list? You also have some blanks within your ranges. When loading an image it is a good idea to ensure the row number are also visible. You can hide rows to get it all in one shot.

Comment: I uploaded an image with my entire range, text in green is the first dropdown and text in red is the depedent drop downs.

Comment: Is there anyone who could help me understand this code?